# Drinking the wine that spills over the cup during Kiddush

Tags: sources-mekorot, kiddush, grapes-wine, eating

There is a widespread custom among the Jewish people to fill up their kiddush cup to the point that it overflows. This overflowing of wine symbolizes Hashems blessing overflowing in our lives. I was told by someone that this wine is compared to the wine that we spill out during Pesach for the ten makkos which al pi kaballah is a high level of klippah and shouldnt even be touched let alone drunk.

Question: What if any is the source that one should not drink the wine that spills out of the kiddush cup as described above.

Comment: Do you want answers of sources permitting?

Comment: I've only seen that minhag by havdalah not kiddush.

Comment: @DoubleAA The spilling or the drinking of the spilled wine? I have seen the spilling over done in 95% of the kiddushim I have witnessed.

Comment: @mochinrechavim It was the minhag of the Rebbe to use some of the spilled wine in the charoses for the maror. Is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: @mochinrechavim, it must be dependent on _minhag_. I've seen it done by Lubavitchers and I think by others too (_chasidim_ IIRC_, but certainly not by most people I've seen make _kidush_.

Comment: @msh210 The Rama quotes the minhag by Havdala in OC 296:1. I'm not aware of anyone quoting it anywhere else. EDIT: The Rama by regular kosei bracha in 183:2 says it should be completely full, but doesn't mention spilling. The Mishna Berura there brings an argument if you are allowed to fill it up so high that some might spill, implying spilling is only bedieved.

Comment: @DoubleAA What makes you think the M.B. says spilling is not ideal?

Comment: @DoubleAA re "I'm not aware of...", answers to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16428) may help you find such a source; otherwise, [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: In a related Gemara, (Eruvin 65a-b) R. Hanin says that if wine is spilled in your house like water there is a bruchah, if not, not. I think the underlying idea of the bruchah is that your wine should be as plentiful as the water in your house, of which you wouldn't care if some spilled since you have so much of it. Therefore, I would think you should not drink the spilled wine since then you are implying that your wine is not as plentiful as water, and you do care if some of it goes to waste.

Comment: @zaq Is that what R. Hanin says? I am looking for a sourced opinion. Your thoughts make a good case though.

Comment: @mochinrechavim - Spilling some out of the cup can make a kos shel b'racha [pagum](http://books.google.com/books?id=1kF9RT8oVg0C&pg=PA131). One must be careful to perform the minhag in a manner that does not violate halacha.

Comment: @mochinrechavim Like I said: The Mishna Berura quotes a machloket about if one is allowed to fill the cup sooo full that it will end up spilling some. One opinion says yes because you're supposed to fill it, the other says no as you are wasting wine. Even for the first opinion, it is clear that spilling is only an unintended consequence not an independent goal. Did you see it inside?

Comment: @zaq Sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: @Fred I believe that would be the subject of a machloket, if spilling can create pagum or not. Some say pagum means drunk from. I'll have to check for a source...

Comment: @mochin rechavim, He says "A person in whose house wine is not poured like water has not attained the state of blessedness".

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't sure if I answered the question, since mochin rechavim is specifically looking for a source that discusses drinking, and I'm really just inferring it.

Comment: How is it possible for any the wine of the kiddush cup to be considered klipa, regardless if it is spilled or not? Doesn't the bracha include any or all of it? If I make a blessing on orange juice and spill a bit, the spilled portion is now unclean? This does not compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eruvin 65a-b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=65&format=pdf):

> R. Hanin b. Papa stated: A person in whose house wine is not poured like water has not
> attained the state of blessedness;
>
> for it is said: And he will bless thy bread and thy water (Mishpatim 23:25) as the 'bread' is food that may be bought with
> the money of the Second Tithe so is the 'water' a liquid that may be
> bought with the money of the Second Tithe. Now such a liquid is of
> course wine, and yet is called 'water'. If therefore, it is poured in
> one's house like water that house has attained to the state of
> blessedness, otherwise it has not.
>
> [iTalmud App]

I think the underlying idea of the bruchah is that your wine should be as plentiful as the water in your house, of which you wouldn't care if some spilled since you have so much of it. Therefore, I would think you should not drink the spilled wine since then you are implying that your wine is not as plentiful as water, and you do care if some of it goes to waste.

Comment: Isn't the very presence of the spilled wine the reason for the blessing? How could that which causes the blessing, and is blessed, be unfit for consumption?