# Minhag of Kos Pagum

Tags: minhag

Another *Minhag* that came from nowhere is the custom of filling a wine cup to overflowing. Some do it because of *Kos Pagum,* however it seems that *Kos Pagum* applies to a cup which is not filled near enough to the top to be considered full. Overflowing the cup is *ba’al tashchis* as well as *davar m’geunah*. Getting wine all over your hands and the tablecloth is not good table manners especially if you are a guest in someone else’s home. The only time there appears to be a reason to do so is *havdalah* when it is considered a *berachah*. Is there a source for this?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/drinking-the-wine-that-spills-over-the-cup-during-kiddush

Comment: @YEZ, it is a common Chassidic Minhag in several groups. Some groups specifically use brimless cups so that it overflows a bit more.

Comment: This question needs a lot of work. The question appears to be part of some kind of ongoing discussion, without any clarity as to where it is coming from. Also, the author seems to be basing his question on sources and personal research that he has not cited.

Comment: "Another Minhag that came from nowhere" Please do not be disrespectful. Also, note, *bal* is Aramaic and is not *ba'al* which is Hebrew and means something different.

Comment: See Rama (OC 296:1) and *Mishna B'rura* ([296:5](http://books.google.com/books?id=1kF9RT8oVg0C&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Answer (score 3):

"Some do it because of Kos Pagum"

The common reason is that an overflowing cup is a b'rocho, as you mention below, and has nothing to do with kos pagum.

"Overflowing the cup is ba’al tashchis"

Because it is done for a reason, it is not "bal tashchis".

"as well as davar m’geunah."

No, it is not. It is a minhag and it is a beautiful one.

"Getting wine all over your hands and the tablecloth is not good table manners especially if you are a guest in someone else’s home."

1. Most people do not make their own havdalah at someone else's house.
2. The Havdalah cup is usually on a plate or in a bowl because the candle is put out in it.
3. People who do not have a plastic on the table cloth probably expect to wash it.

"The only time there appears to be a reason to do so is havdalah"

Some people do it by every kiddush.

Comment: Aw c'mon ... a negative total vote? For answering a question that people commented that the question itself is vague??? I think this answer addresses all the questions pretty well. And yes, my granpa, father and I overflow the kiddush cup. I was taught that it is a sign of thanks to hashem that he has given us brachot during the week so that we can "afford extra wine", i.e. - he blessed us with more than what we need.

Comment: Heh. The tone of my post is not that great, so i can't complain about a negative vote. I started in the comment field, but when i saw it too small, i moved it here. The tone of the original question bothered me. I think i'll move the complaints out. They do not belong there...done.